# Most generic array type?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-4.0

I am looking to create a simple array wrapper with a few helper methods, however I want this wrapper to be able to handle any 1 dimensional array/operation. So I am looking for a base type to cast the internal array to.

Can anyone sugest a type?

Comment: I may be missing the point, but aren't generic lists the same thing? They wrap an 1 dimensional array, add helper functions...

Comment: Can't you just make it generic? `class MyArrayWrapper<T>`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic type parameter:

```
public class ArrayWrapper<T>
{
   private T[] array;
}
```

The [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class encapsulates an array generically and provides a number of helper methods already.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want your helper methods to be written as generic extension methods:

```
public static Array Extensions
{
    public void Foo<T>(this T[] bar)
    {
        //foo this bar
    }
}
```

Since this is an extension method, all arrays will now have an instance method on them called foo:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
a.Foo();
```

Nb. Rereading your question after seeing the other answer, I see you were asking about making a wrapper class. If you prefer a class, the other answer is technically more correct, but if you're just making a couple of helper methods then extension methods are a far better solution to the problem.

Comment: Yeah extensions methods would be fine but in this case it is to solve a really obscure problem where I have to mask all generics. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Out of interest, what's the obscure problem?

Comment: Updating an old FORTRAN application to use .Net objects for data aquisition, however FORTRAN can't handle generics so I need to mask them with none generic types.

Answer (score 3):

Why not a set of extension methods?

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static void MyFoo<T>(this T[] sourceArray)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```